# Consuming WCF Service in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a WCF Service which I'm consuming in MVC3 application. Now I have a new project of MVC4 in which I want to consume the same service, but I'm not getting the Service class for creating the object.

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client obj = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
```

This line is giving me error. My MVC4 project is completely new with Empty template in which I have added a controller and trying to access the service class in it.

Comment: Are you sure you have inserted the WCF Service in References? Have you also added a using statement for that Service in the class?

Comment: Yes @Subby I have added the service reference of that WCF service in my MVC4 project and accessing it with the namespace as stated in the question.

Comment: What is the error? Did the service reference get generated without errors?

Comment: Not getting any error while adding the service reference. even getting the methods names when I discover the service while adding. But after adding the service reference I didn't get the ServiceClass for creating the service object

Comment: _"This line is giving me error."_ - **what error**?

Comment: Its a compile time error. Not able to create the object as I'm not getting the Service class. Refer my previous comment.

Comment: Same error is for me. ANy answers?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

http://www.naveenbhat.in/2013/07/mvc-4-wcf-add-service-reference.html

Hope this helps.

Seems some update is missing with the VS.

Comment: As of today, the referenced website is down and possibly not working anymore. This scenario is precisely why it's better to cite specific examples from any source and then provide the link as a source. Much like writing a paper and citing your sources.

Comment: @janoulle: Can yo double check the link? Its working.